# htmlText embedded images not properly aligned

Tags: actionscript-3, htmltext

I have a TextField and I am trying to display embedded images using htmlText:

```
var test:TextField = new TextField();
test.multiline = true;
test.wordWrap = true;
test.htmlText = 
  "<b>Texttextext:</b> <br> \
  <br> <br> test <img src = '" + "Assets_raftImg" + "'/>sfsf";
```

In this case the raftImg is in the Assets class. The problem is that the image does not align as it should (it always stays in upper left corner). If I load it using "../blah/img.gif" it works properly.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`TextField.htmlText`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) reference says :

> src: Specifies the URL to an image or
>   SWF file, or the linkage identifier
>   for a movie clip symbol in the library

did you try

```
[Embed(source="../blah/img.gif", symbol="raftImg")]
var test:TextField = new TextField();
test.multiline = true;
test.wordWrap = true;
test.htmlText = 
  "<b>Texttextext:</b> <br> \
  <br> <br> test <img src = '" + "raftImg" + "'/>sfsf";
```

?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with AS3, but isn't the symbol property used to get a specific asset from another swf? In either case, when compiling I got the error that symbol cannot be used with the gif parser.